# How to deploy AWSCLI into AWS Lambda with serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-cli, serverless

[Here](https://github.com/alestic/aws-git-backed-static-website/blob/master/build-upload-aws-lambda-function) are instructions on how to package `awscli` into lambda, but [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/) uses docker for [lambda packaging](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-python-requirements) - is there a way to include these instructions into serverless build process (e.g. affect docker image)?

Comment: Using the awscli in Lambda doesn't seem to be ideal. I'd consider using Python and boto3 (or equivalent) if what you're doing is simple enough (e.g. most things other than `aws s3 sync`).

Comment: I **understand** but need cli :-)

Comment: Why? Execing an executable which itself has dependencies on Python and other things is hardly ideal in Lambda (or anywhere tbh). What are you using awscli for?

Comment: 1) to run any awscli command in lambda which simpler then setup EC2 especially when it comes to run command during step-functions execution. 2) For now I need was s3 sync, which have some optimization and works faster than a simple python loop for one by one objects copy.

Comment: Btw, somebody already created `s3 sync` in lambda, the question - just how to do this via serverless.